# If I buy games via the Origin store do I need to install it?

Tags: origin

I wanted to buy Dead Space 2 as a digital download (because I want to play it ASAP and because it is cheaper). The official site does not allow you to buy the game but I can get it via the Origin store.

Am I forced to use Origin to get my game after I bought it there?

If so for what aspects do I need Origin? (Origin has bad reputation that's why I want to avoid it)

Comment: Its also available via steam http://store.steampowered.com/app/47780

Comment: @Nick no i cannot buy it on steam. maybe because i am from germany. if i search for dead space 2 i dont get any results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you buy a game through the Origin store, then, yes, you need to download and install the game through Origin.  Buying a game just allows you to download the game from that location; it does *not* allow you to play it without installing it.

Origin is just like Steam; it's a digital download platform which allows you to purchase and subsequently download and play those games.  The only ones you don't need to install are those that are completely browser-based, in which case, you wouldn't need Steam OR Origin.

Comment: Saying Origin is just like Steam is like suggesting that an old Pinto has more than a few things in common with the Batmobile -- and I have my doubts about EA's ability to improve any of it.

Comment: I personally have never had any issues with Origin, and it does get better each which new release

Comment: While i never had any real issues with origin i have found it to be slow and unresponsive a lot of times. also the amount of games origin has compared to steam makes steam the better choice.

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp: As always, if choice is what you are after the best choice is "both".

Comment: i downloaded and installed it via origin. after that i uninstalled origin and can still play the game as i please. but some extra content requires origin which sucks.